# There is no feature named VERSION_CATALOGS

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

Hi All, above is my AGP Version and Gradle Version.

```
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
    }
}

include ':app'
```

I try to apply code above at settings.gradle(project name).

But I get error

> There is no feature named VERSION_CATALOGS

Can anyone please help?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature preview flag was added in Gradle 7.0.0 and removed in Gradle 8.0.0. So with Gradle 6.2 you cannot use it.